# CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/current_repodata.json>

Tags: python

when I tried to run this command in macOS 13.3 with M1 pro chip, show error like this:

```
> conda install anaconda-clean
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/current_repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
'https//conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
```

I have tried to set the ssl verify:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

I also have tried to switch the network from wifi(contains proxy) to 4G. Still did not fixed this issue. what should I do to make the conda work? BTW, I can access the url https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64/current_repodata.json in google chrome browser and terminal using curl command.